# Hyperledger, Peer port not starting properly

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Since I am new to blockchain. While I try to install the blockchain I meet this error.
[image: Hyperledger Port not open 7050, 7051, 7052, 7053...]

Normally I should able to see this stat.

[image: Proper installation]

- Note: I didn't install it in Vagrant and Vbox or docker environment. 
  I just install it directly on Server, Would it can be the cause of the problems ?

Answer (score 0):

Installing Hyperledger Fabric version 0.6 directly on a server is not a path that is commonly followed.  Using published Docker images is the easiest approach for someone that is new to blockchain.  Another approach is to create a development environment which will use Vagrant.  Related information for Hyperledger Fabric 0.6 is located [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/v0.6/docs/Setup/Network-setup.md).

Comment: Really appreciate for your help.
I try few different ways. Now I can install it directly since I miss understand in version of fabric. I used version 1.0 but follow v0.6

Comment: but now I face problem in forming a network with 3 different peers and separated servers.
I hope you can visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360844/hyperledger-fabric-v0-6-set-up-network-additional-peer-directly-without-docke to see more detail