# Hyperledger Fabric v0.6, set up network (additional peer) directly without docker any possible way?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, peer

I has a question related to network setup of additional peer in Hyperledger Fabric.
I want to add 2 more peers to existing peer to form a network ,but all available document is all about connection peer together by using Docker. In my case I already have multiple servers. so I just directly install peers to 3 different Servers separately ,but how can I connect that 3 peer up and running together. I cannot find any document related to this.
Hopp you can guide.

To install Fabric directly to Server is recommend or not?
Below is Screenshot of one peer. it's up and running fine. but How to connect 3 peers together directly on different Server without using Docker.
I have follow this link: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/Setup/Network-setup.md
but I still can't find the way since it used docker.
any file that can modify to make it such as core.yaml ..etc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/homs9.png)

Answer (score 2):

When using Hyperledger Fabric version 0.6, there is not a straightforward way to connect multiple peers on different servers without using Docker.  As you noted, the [Setting Up a Network](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/Setup/Network-setup.md) section covers how to use Docker Compose to link peers together.  One of the primary uses of a Hyperledger Fabric version 0.6 network is to learn how to develop chaincode.  The focus isn't so much on dynamically allowing peers to join a network.

There are a few options for creating a blockchain network for Hyperledger Fabric version 0.6.

- [Published Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmblockchain/fabric-peer/)
- Setting up a [development environment](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/v0.6/docs/Setup/Network-setup.md)
- An instance of the Blockchain service on Bluemix can be created.

Hyperledger Fabric 1.0 (currently under development) aims to make it easier for different entities to join a blockchain network.  An early preview of related concepts were covered during a [Connect-A-Thon event](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/connectathon).  There is also an [article](https://cointelegraph.com/news/ibms-first-connect-a-thon-to-build-ecosystem-on-its-blockchain) about this event.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We can create a blockchain network without docker using Hyperledger Fabric v0.6. We have been done it in practice. For sure, we have to use docker to deploy chaincode.

For Hyperledger Fabric v0.6, both with docker or without it, we can not add more peers to existing network.